# iPhone SDK UIWebView with Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have trouble accomplishing something that sounds very simple. Using Interface Builder, I created a UIWebView object. Next, I created a new controller - HomeViewController and assigned it to the WebView under "NIB Name" property. 
Next I need to load a web site (let's say http://google.com) into that WebView when user accesses that view. I am not able to find any examples on how to actually accomplish this. Please provide a code example. Sorry about the newbie question. I did RTFM, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The .h file:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
#import "WebViewController.h"

@implementation WebViewController

// Loads the url when the view loads
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Request Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

@end
```

Comment: Those quotes are messed up, but I can't edit the post, because it needs at least 6 characters edited :/. Copy pasters, change the qoutes if you get errors. Other than that, it works perfectly, +1.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]]; // webview - your Uiwebview object
```

Comment: Can you please provide context for this? Where does this go and where does "webview" object come from? This is a nib-based UIWebView object, so how do I reference it in code?

Comment: Create IBoutlet for UiWebview in your .h file and connect it in NIB file.

eg. IBoutlet UiWebview *webview;